# Have a Unix command/script  work on windows?

Tags: windows, shell, unix

I have this command that is using a unix pipe

```
 system("curl " . escapeshellarg($flv['dl']) . " | ffmpeg -f flv -i - -f mp3 -ab 320k pipe:1");
```

what could I do to make the same thing happen in windows?

Thanks

Comment: The `system()` call implies you're executing this shell statement from some other language... the `.` suggests perl.  Even the Windows command prompt supports pipes, so if you change the above to simply print the commandline, you can try executing the same thing manually from the Windows command prompt.  Your real issue may well be getting `curl` and `ffmpeg` installed and their paths added to your PATH environment variable, without needing to a UNIX-style shell.

Comment: Hello @Jim Garrison,
Why would you remove cygwin tag ?

Comment: @Tony - escapeshellarg() is a PHP function

Comment: @lunixbochs: thanks for the insight.  A super-quick skim of the PHP docs suggests PHP's `system` also just passes the instruction through to the OS's default command interpreter without internally handling the pipe, so it still seems to be a matter of getting curl and ffmpeg installed and in the PATH, without any change to the PHP code necessary....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are **not concerned with performance**, the easiest way to port a unix script to windows is by installing [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.org).

It's a Unix API emulation layer over Windows likewise Wine emulates win32 on linux.

---

You could also download windows version of each command line tools

- see [Curl download](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) provide several windows version binary ( don t take the cygwin version.
- Note that [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) is only available as nightly build for windows. No stable release compiled.

This approach requires to find specific download url for each tool and sometimes even leads you to compile binary from source code ! It is still reasonable when you only need 2 or 3 tools. But otherwise, it is so uncertain and time consuming that you should only consider when performance or low dependancy deployment is an issue.

Comment: But note that Wine runs **unmodified** windows binaries, whereas Cygwin requires that you recompile your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the file downloaded by curl to ffmpeg by pipe is the best way, I think.

curl "http://domain.com/file.flv" | ffmpeg -f flv -i - -f mp3 -ab 320k pipe:1

curl & ffmpeg are available for windows.